# GitHub creating submodule instead of a simple folder

Tags: git, github, repository, git-submodules, git-remote

I'm creating a repository as usual following [these steps recommended by GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line):

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin remote repository URL
git remote -v
git push origin master
```

I don't know the reason why but instead of creating simple folders there are being created submodules as shown in the image below

[image: backend created successfully as a folder but frontend created as submodule]

Notice that backend has been created normaly as a folder but frontend was created as a subfolder, like some compiled code that I cannot se the items inside...

Does anybody know the reason? Did I make any mistake when creating the repo?

Comment: Is there a `.git` directory inside `frontend`?

Comment: @GoodDeeds yes...

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thanks man! Saved the day! It's such a simple thing but I wouldn't even imagine...please, answer my question so I can mark the post solved!

Comment: Good to hear. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clarified in the comments, you have `.git` directory inside the `frontend` directory.

That means `frontend` is initialized as a separate git repository. If you don't need this you can simply delete the `.git` directory inside, commit, push, and continue.